# ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DoctrineFixturesBundle"

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I have this return symfony error with all my url website : 
"**ClassNotFoundException: Attempted to load class "DoctrineFixturesBundle" from namespace "Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle" in C:\dev\Apache2.4.6\htdocs\MySite\app\AppKernel.php line 23. Do you need to "use" it from another namespace?**"

This error appear when I modified the config.yml (part doctrine orm)for resolve others problem but it's not resolving. Indeed a back my change in this file and re-run my website but now nothing run correctly. I have this error anytime and anywhere.

I copy my code here but for response at simple question :
- *do you have adding this line in AppKernel.php* : $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(); ? **RESPONSE : YES** 
- *do you have install fixtures bundle ?* **RESPONSE : YES** 
- *do you have install/update and self-update composer ?*  **RESPONSE : YES** 
- *do you have load fixtures in DB ?* **RESPONSE : YES (it run perfectly)** 
- *do you have cleaning the cache ?* **RESPONSE : YES**

All my fixtures engine run correctly just before this generate error.

AppKernel.php

```
        if (in_array($this->getEnvironment(), array('dev', 'test'))) {
        $bundles[] = new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Symfony\Bundle\WebProfilerBundle\WebProfilerBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\DistributionBundle\SensioDistributionBundle();
        $bundles[] = new Sensio\Bundle\GeneratorBundle\SensioGeneratorBundle();
    }
```

composer.json

```
    "require": {
    "php": ">=5.3.3",
    "symfony/symfony": "~2.4",
    "doctrine/orm": "2.4.2",
    "doctrine/doctrine-bundle": "~1.2",
    "twig/extensions": "~1.0",
    "symfony/assetic-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle": "~2.3",
    "symfony/monolog-bundle": "~2.4",
    "sensio/distribution-bundle": "~2.3",
    "sensio/framework-extra-bundle": "~3.0",
    "sensio/generator-bundle": "~2.3",
    "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler": "~2.0",
    "doctrine/doctrine-fixtures-bundle": "dev-master"
},
```

config.yml

```
doctrine:
dbal:
    driver:   "%database_driver%"
    host:     "%database_host%"
    port:     "%database_port%"
    dbname:   "%database_name%"
    user:     "%database_user%"
    password: "%database_password%"
    charset:  UTF8
    # if using pdo_sqlite as your database driver, add the path in parameters.yml
    # e.g. database_path: "%kernel.root_dir%/data/data.db3"
    # path:     "%database_path%"

orm:
    auto_generate_proxy_classes: "%kernel.debug%"
    auto_mapping: true
```

Thank for your precious help

Answer (score 3):

very strange behaviour because it's solve automaticaly and alone.
After lot of cache:clear, delete cache manually, comment/decomment line in AppKernel.php this issue solve.

But A new begin...

Now this is my dev toolbar symfony which don't run.

I think create a new topic for this new problem for don't mixing with this.

Comment: Me too, i had this problem, i think that it is caused by copying/psting code from windows to unix plateforms (such as Ubuntu). For me every time, i copy code from windows to unix, i get this error.

Comment: I don't know if your comment detail the cause of my actual issue but I already view the kind of error with work in same time with linux and windows as you say.

Answer (score 1):

I'he got the same wierd error on

```
new Application\Extended\SonataMediaBundle\ExtendedSonataMediaBundle()
```

In my case it gone back to work after I fixed **composer.json** file and runned **composer update**. To be correct, first time I initiated "composer update" without composer.json fixes and error not disappeared, so "composer update" itself is not a solution, the key thing - is composer.json file fix.

This is even stranger because it was *wrong* fix - I removed slash in psr-0 autoload definition, so having:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "/": "src/" }
},
```

i got:

```
"autoload": {
    "psr-0": { "": "src/" }
},
```

Thats only one slash! **And it is wrong fix because composer suggest to not use empty namespace**:

```
$ composer validate 
./composer.json is valid, but with a few warnings
See https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md for details on the schema
Defining autoload.psr-0 with an empty namespace prefix is a bad idea for performance
```

Note 1: *it worked with that slash in previous days* and stoped to work today, pretty strange.  Project were untouched in time between two working states!

Note 2: initial (in-box) state of composer.json file is without slash, I added it two weeks ago to suppress composer's dissatisfaction.

Comment: I don't know if your response resolve my issue but I think this is useful and interested response. Thank you for your response.